# Galaxy S3 running jellybean 4.3 - Custom Rom Concern

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing

I have a galaxy s3 running jellybean 4.3 as mentioned above. Following recent news there will NOT be a further update to the KitKat 4.4 version

My plan is to root and flash with a custom ROM, however, a big part of the problem is that I have a Gear 2 Neo, which uses samsung apps and more importantly Gear Manager, will I still have access to this after I flash the custom ROM

Also will I be able to still get google play store on my device

Thanks

Comment: Recommendations don't fit this site very well because they're opinion-based, rather than having a correct answer we can all agree on. You'll get more helpful answers if you [edit] your question down to focus on the fact-based part about Gear Manager.

Comment: Hi Dan, I appreciate your comment and it is true, I normally use StackOverFlow for programming help and always get sound advice, that why I came onto here so that I'm not having anyone answer my question, is there a sort of discussion part of the website I could post this too which would be more appropriate?

Comment: No. If you're looking to have a general discussion, there are several web fora you could do that. See http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/12442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for custom ROMS, even for "older" phones such as the S3.

Personally I would recommend Paranoid Android ROM as it's very "Googley". I run it on my HTC One X and it's very good. You can get started with that by looking on the [XDA community](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/orig-development/aospaandroid-4-4-2-kvt49l-t1745003) for that device.

Unfortunately, you will have to wipe your apps and data, *but* if you are rooted you can do a backup with something like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en).

You may be able to get away with just installing the apk for Gear Manager, there are many people that have reported that this works on other devices.

Yes, you will still have access to the play store if you flash the correct gapps for your device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the first thing I was going to do after some research was Root my device, I've found a good download file and instructions for this.

I'll then do what you said and back-up my apps to an SD card and remove during the flash process. 

With regards to Gear Manager, is that my only option?